# Generalized number base system

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a function or a representation for natural numbers that satisfies:
$$ f(1) = 11 \\ f(2) = 12 \\ f(3) = 13 \\ f(4) = 14 \\ f(5) = 21 \\ f(6) = 22 \\ f(7) = 23 \\ f(8) = 24 \\ f(9) = 31 \\...$$

Background:

In combinatorics, this is a representation of [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). For examples: all possible ways of choosing 2 hats {1, 2} and 4 shoes {1, 2, 3, 4} are: 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called a [mixed radix numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) (but I may be wrong)

Comment: So base four but with no zeros.....Just let $a_na_{n-1}....a_1a_0 = [\sum_{k=0}^n (a_k-1)4^{k}]+1$.  Nothing wrong with that.  (Don't see what to gain but nothing to lose.)  I don't see why you started at with two digits instead of one.

Comment: @user170231, It's something similar to that, but here the numbers are concatenated in one number.

Comment: The same could be said for base $10$ numerals. The number $12_{10}$ is just the concatenation of $1$ and $2$, with both digits being pulled from the same set $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$. For a mixed radix system, the only difference is that the set for each place value is different.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the pattern here is that the last digit of the function evaluated at a number $n$ is just the $n(mod4)$, where if you get $0$, you put a $4$ instead. The second last digit is $\lceil n/4 \rceil(mod4)$, here again, if you get $0$, you put $4$ instead. Ok, the $i^{th}$ from the last digit is $\lceil \frac{n}{4^{i-1}} \rceil(mod4)$ and again, you put a $4$ if you get $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but Is there a more rigirous formula for this?